# C# regex match return false

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my code for c# regex match:

```
String pa = "(?<year>\\d{2, 4})/(?<month>\\d{1, 2})/(?<day>\\d{1, 2})";
Match match = Regex.Match("2014/03/02", pa);
```

But `match.success` returns false. What is the problem?

Comment: There is a typo: the whitespace inside a limiting quantifier is *meaningful*.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your expression: `(?<year>[0-9]{2,4})\/(?<month>[0-9]{1,2})\/(?<day>[0-9]{1,2})`

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/cJ4sxi/1

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the spaces in your `{2, 4}` and `{1, 2}` quantifiers.